# Your account has been automatically suspended for posting inappropriate content

Tags: discussion, chat

OrigamiRobot has been repeatedly harassing me the past few months.  Everytime I join chat, to talk about anything, he will constantly harass me by [quoting](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8694616#8694616) something I said a long time ago.  Even though I have asked repeatedly for him to stop annoying me, he has continued to do the same thing over, and over, and over again.

If this issue continues, I have no problem filing a mod abuse report to `team@stackexchange.com`

Comment: OrigamiRobot is not a mod. His actions are, *by definition* not mod abuse.

Comment: You know, I find it ironic that you bought this up in chat and then did it yourself. It didn't work when I did it either but I wasn't sat in chat giving people abuse...

Comment: Oh, sweet sweet irony.

Comment: Really? He told me I was obnoxious after I pinged him ONCE.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8697106#8697106

Comment: [You will not beat me at the quote game](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8697132#8697132)

Comment: I know, on multiple occasions, I've pointed out something to you, and you've attacked me for it.  If a half-dozen people are telling you your attitude needs work, and you get banned *three* times in one day, maybe it's not the community that's in the wrong, here.

Comment: Hmmm perhaps I should check the chat out more for my daily dose of drama :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By all means, bring it up to us if you'd like... We respond to every email we get and we investigate all issues brought to us.

I must say, though, that coming to meta and just threatening to do that is a bit weird. Let's try to solve what looks like a fairly simple interpersonal issue before we escalate to the next level. Have you tried flagging these annoying messages for moderator attention and asking a site moderator to look into things first?

If all else fails, you can always ignore OrigamiRobot (or any other user) in chat and avoid seeing their messages altogether. Click on his name in chat and either choose "hide posts" (this is temporary and will reset if you refresh the page) or "ignore this user (everywhere)" (this is permanent until you explicitly unignore him).

I'm going to hold off on taking action based on this meta post to give the community here a chance to resolve things, but as I said earlier, don't hesitate to contact us with any issues or requests.

Comment: Everytime I flag anything, OrigamiRobot continually harasses me with his messages. I don't have a direct link, but he always quotes himself saying "Don't flag stupid things".  Even though I've been flagging some right things (people attacking people in chat), no matter what I do, some certain user seems to berate me for flagging.

Comment: @Retrosaur Flagging one of their posts on the site might be a better approach if you want flag privacy. Chat flags are unfortunately not great for that. I apologize in advance if what I say next is wrong cause I can never quite remember how chat flags work. If you click the arrow on the left of a chat message, and then click "flag for moderator"... that'll bring up a popup where you can enter a custom flag reason that will only be visible to moderators and not 10k chat users. I believe that will still include moderators across SE and not just on Gaming, though.

Comment: [Here is one instance of me telling someone not to flag stupid things.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=8098570#8098570) [Here is another.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8125869#8125869)  I can distinctly remember the 2nd example being yet another time @Retrosaur was complaining about others posting "spoilers" and flagging them just because it was something he was suspended for.

Answer (score 7):

Once upon a time, you got suspended for posting spoilers in chat.  I wasn't a part of that and I even think it was silly.  Later, you [claimed you wanted to be less obnoxious](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8112267#8112267).  I thought, "Good for him." and carried on about my day.  Since then, every time I see you in chat, you are either pretending to talk about spoilers, or trying to find examples of other people talking about spoilers.  Each time, I subtly reminded you of your own goal of being less obnoxious.  Perhaps it was too subtle.

Also, you never once, until just before your recent suspension, asked me to stop.

Today, *you* were repeatedly harassing kalina and from what I could see, this was 100% unprovoked.  You were suspended for 30 minutes and went right back to being disruptive when your suspension was over.